# Xcode 5 - updated provision profile, but is it using my latest?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-provisioning

I'm familiar with the new Xcode setup of going to Preferences > Accounts > View Details... and then the 'refresh button' in order to show all provisioning profiles.

But what happens if I update an existing profile? For example I added new devices to the profile. Back in Xcode I press refresh, but there's no indication it's using the latest one. You might think it will because I did a refresh, but in the past I've pressed that refresh button and didn't really get updated (apple servers are slow to process the changes sometimes).

So I'm in a gray area. I want to release the app to a client to test, but I don't really want to go through all that 'app could not be installed on this device' stuff. It would be great if it somewhere showed - 'updated 2/5/14' .. but I don't see that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want details about the provisioning profiles that you have added to Xcode, you can download the [iPhone Configuration Utility](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1465) and it will show you information about your profiles, such as how many devices are in them, their creation and expiration dates, and app ID. It will also let you delete profiles, so you can delete old profiles that have expired, and remove duplicates if it has two versions of a particular profile.

Comment: Thanks this helped. Xcode actually had erased my old provision profile but was not downloading the new version after multiple attempts and restarts. I used the Configuration Utility to manually add the profile and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

1.You have to check the code signing settings of your target! Is your old or you new profile there?

2.If the new prov profile is in place, and the XCode 5 does not build with it, you have to restart the XCode!